# My mobile navbar(Bootstrapmade) dont work

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

My problem is, that my mobile navbar dont work and i cant figure out why.
I searched up on much websites but cant find anything what i did wrong.
Of course i changed this but i still dont know what and my mobile navbar dont show up:
Image: https://prnt.sc/BH-gA0TxumST
Here you can see, that the menu is almost there but when i click, nothing happens.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title>Astra | Discord bot</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Astra &middot; Discord Bot" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="/assets/img/favicon.png" />
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="Astra manages your server - you can handle your discord server with Astra: Administration, level system, temp channels, welcome message, and much more." />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#5846f9">
    <link href="assets/img/favicon_transparent.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="assets/img/favicon_transparent.png" rel="favicon_transparent">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include_once 'templates/header.php';
?>
```

header.php

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top ">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <a href="https://astra-bot.de/" class="logo"><img src="../assets/img/Astra_Stern.png" alt="" ></a>
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <ul >
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="https://astra-bot.de/#hero">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="https://astra-bot.de/#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="https://astra-bot.de/#team">Team</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="https://astra-bot.de/#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="https://astra-bot.de/#faq">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a class="file" href="commands">Commands</a></li>
                <li><a class="getstarted" href="./invite.php">Invite</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

css

```
/**
* Template Name: Techie - v4.3.0
* Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/techie-free-skin-bootstrap-3/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
* License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
}

a {
  color: #5846f9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #8577fb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Back to top button
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 996;
  background: #5846f9;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.back-to-top i {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 0;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
  background: #7b27d8;
  color: #fff;
}

.circular--square {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.back-to-top.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #373131;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #5846f9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #686868;
}


::selection {
  color: #5846f9;
  background-color: #69c1e4;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Preloader
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #36393e;
}

#preloader:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  border: 6px solid #5846f9;
  border-top-color: #e7e4fe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: animate-preloader 1s linear infinite;
  animation: animate-preloader 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-preloader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-preloader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Disable aos animation delay on mobile devices
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-aos-delay] {
    transition-delay: 0 !important;
  }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#header.header-scrolled, #header.header-inner-pages {
  background: rgba(24, 6, 185, 0.8);
  padding: 12px 0;
}

#header .logo {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header .logo a {
  color: #fff;
}

#header .logo img {
  max-height: 40px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
* Desktop Navigation
*/
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar > ul > li {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 24px;
}

.navbar a, .navbar a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a i, .navbar a:focus i {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar > ul > li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before, .navbar li:hover > a:before, .navbar .active:before {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a:hover, .navbar .active, .navbar .active:focus, .navbar li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .getstarted {
  padding: 8px 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.navbar .getstarted:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.navbar .getstarted:before, .navbar li:hover > .getstarted:before {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 24px;
  top: calc(100% + 30px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul li {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2c4964;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a:hover, .navbar .dropdown ul .active:hover, .navbar .dropdown ul li:hover > a {
  color: #5846f9;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
    left: -90%;
  }
  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover > ul {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

/**
* Mobile Navigation
*/
.mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar ul {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(28, 47, 65, 0.9);
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-mobile .mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar-mobile > ul > li {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-mobile a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #2c4964;
}

.navbar-mobile a:hover:before, .navbar-mobile li:hover > a:before, .navbar-mobile .active:before {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar-mobile a:hover, .navbar-mobile .active, .navbar-mobile li:hover > a {
  color: #5846f9;
}

.navbar-mobile .getstarted {
  margin: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a:hover, .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul .active:hover, .navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li:hover > a {
  color: #5846f9;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown > .dropdown-active {
  display: block;
}
```

it would be nice if someone can have a look at it and tell me what i did wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this site responsive. check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582319/responsiveness-in-mobile-view-for-portfolio-landing-page/72582388#72582388). Otherwise, if you are using bootstrap, you need to import the bootstrap CSS file. Add this line to the head of the HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

visit [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) for many details. This code will help you to get bootstrap 4.0

If you are using different classes which does not have a bootstrap class, you need to make them responsive manually. This is its basic structure of it. You need to customize all your elements to the appropriate sizes. For more details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582319/responsiveness-in-mobile-view-for-portfolio-landing-page/72582388#72582388)

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    h1, .h01 {
        font-size: 2.6rem;
        letter-spacing: -.07rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Shenal Akalanka, li get always the same problem after adding this line to my header. Did you have any other ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: I hope the new method will help you to fix your problem.

Comment: Hey Shenal Akalanka again, i tried your new method but it still dont work on my mobile phone. Would be nice if you have any other ideas.